# A question from test: choose one of then, since, after, that

Tags: time-words, time-reference

Here is a question from a test:

> It was only ten years ago ... she started her new job
>
> 1. then
> 2. since
> 3. after
> 4. that

As far as I remember, the correct answer is "*that*" (fourth one), but I have no the slightest idea why it is so.

Can anybody tell what piece of grammar it is and/or explain why "*that*" is the correct answer?

Comment: See this for more information: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses. The answer and its comments are quite thorough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three aren't grammatical for these reasons:

- the structure *X **then** Y* requires X and Y to be events. The phrase "It was only ten years ago" isn't an event; and
- the structure *X **since/after** Y* requires X to be a *duration* (e.g. ten years). The phrase *ten years ago* is a specific point in time, not a duration.